# Which assert* to use with comparing SELECT statements from MYSQL and MSSQL pre-migration

Tags: java, mysql, sql, data-migration

I keep getting assertion errors when I send this QUERY to the database even though when I manually enter in the query into both databases it return the correct data.

The only difference is the column title sown literally below(left is the MYSQL and right is MSSQL)

```
_____________________________________________
count(*)     |     (No Column Name)
_____________________________________________
43           |           43
             |
```

Here is my JAVA Code

```
public class UnitTestDMUtility_Select {


@Test
public void testQUERY_CHECKBOTHPARTS() throws Exception{

    UnitTestHelper helper = new UnitTestHelper();
    Connection con = helper.getConnection(helper.sourceDBUrl);
    Connection conTarget = helper.getConnection(helper.targetDBUrl);


    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(DMUtility.QUERY_CHECKBOTHPARTS);
    stmt.setInt(1, 101);
    ResultSet sourceVal = stmt.executeQuery();
    //Here is the QUERY
    //select count(*) from tr_demand where demandtypeid=101
    stmt = conTarget.prepareStatement(DMUtility.QUERY_CHECKBOTHPARTS);
    stmt.setInt(1, 101);
    ResultSet targetVal = stmt.executeQuery();

    assertTrue(helper.resultSetsEqual2(sourceVal,targetVal));

}

}

package a7.unittests.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class UnitTestHelper {




public Connection getConnection(String url)throws Exception{
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url);
}

/*
 * Use for Insert and Update and Delete Statements
 */

public boolean resultSetsEqual4 (int source, int target){

    System.out.println("The source is: "+source+" The target is: "+target);
    if(((source>0)&&(target>0)&&(target==source)))
    {

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

/*
 * Used to test SELECT statements passing in objects
 */


public boolean resultSetsEqual2 (ResultSet source, ResultSet target) throws SQLException{
    System.out.println("The source is: "+source+" The target is: "+target);
    while(source.next())
    {
        target.next();
        ResultSetMetaData metadata = source.getMetaData();
        int count = metadata.getColumnCount();
        for (int i =1; i<=count; i++)
        {
            if(!source.getObject(i).equals(target.getObject(i)))
            {return false;}
        }
    }
    return true;
}


public boolean resultSetsEqual (ResultSet source, ResultSet target) throws SQLException{

System.out.println("The source is: "+source+" The target is: "+target);
while(source.next())
{
    target.next();
    ResultSetMetaData metadata = source.getMetaData();
    int count = metadata.getColumnCount();
    for (int i =1; i<=count; i++)
    {
        if(source.getObject(i) != target.getObject(i))
        {return false;}
    }
}
return true;
}
public boolean resultSetsEqual3 (ResultSet rs1, ResultSet rs2) throws SQLException {
int col = 1;
//ResultSetMetaData metadata = rs1.getMetaData();
//int count = metadata.getColumnCount();
while (rs1.next() && rs2.next()) {
    final Object res1 = rs1.getObject(col);
    final Object res2 = rs2.getObject(col);
    // Check values
    if (!res1.equals(res2)) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("%s and %s aren't equal at common position %d",
            res1, res2, col));
    }
    // rs1 and rs2 must reach last row in the same iteration
    if ((rs1.isLast() != rs2.isLast())) {
        throw new RuntimeException("The two ResultSets contains different number of columns!");
    }  
}
return true;
}
}
```

Comment: select count(*) from tr_demand where demandtypeid=?

Comment: And is your problem in `resultSetsEqual()`, `resultSetsEqual2()`, `resultSetsEqual3()` or `resultSetsEqual4()` ? Also it's not common practice to expose usernames and passwords on the internet. You might want to change those now.

Comment: It might very well be, because it is failing at the assertTrue(...) line.  But when I ran the Test using the targetDB(MSSQL) and the sourceDB(MSSQL) being the same DBURL it passed.  I did that to make sure it was working on at least the source.

Comment: OK thanks, I'm doing it now.  Do you hava an answer?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will help, but if you know it's going to be a number, don't use `getObject()`, but use `getInt()` and compare those values with `==`.